# Use JS script file in angular library

Tags: angular, ng-packagr

I am trying to create an angular library in which one of the service has to make use of [web-sdk.js](https://api.zopim.com/web-sdk) file  by importing it.
Everything is working perfectly fine when I create that service inside of the application itself rather than a library, but there are some reason because of which I would rather have this service inside of a library.

Import statement that works in application but not in the library.

```
import sdk from '../../assets/web-sdk.js';
```

In the angular library I also tried entering a full path to the js file, but the I just get an error `default' is not exported by...`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to solve it by creating a folder with the JS file and `.d.ts` file and adding this folder to the package.json dependency list - `"sdk": "file:./external/sdk"`.

After running `yarn install` I was able to make use of the JS lib by importing it - `import sdk from 'sdk';`

Answer (score -1):

I was also facing same issue, you should add your js script file in node_modules and import it from there.

create a folder containing your js file at your package.json level

assume folder custom-sdk,

then in package.json inside scripts add this line

```
"postinstall": "rm -r -f node_modules/@custom-sdk && cp custom-sdk node_modules/@custom-sdk -r"
```

this command will create a folder name @custom-sdk in your node_modules,

this postinstall command will run after "npm i" automatically so you need to use "npm i" once before using it in library

and then import in library like this

```
import sdk from '@custom-sdk/web-sdk.js';
```

It will work!!!

the postinstall command will run in bash terminal only if you run in other terminals it throw error.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Shortly after posting the question I was able to find a solution as well. I created a folder with the sdk, created a d.ts file and added package.json (not sure if those two were really necessary) and added that folder as a dependency to the package.json file